# Solr Search for near matches

Tags: solr

Hi I want to search in the solr for near matches I mean If I query for "manage" then it should look for "manager", "management" etc but not "man". I am currently using String field which matches exactly which I don't want. Please suggest some filters or analyzer through which I can achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for prefix search?

Comment: Ya prefix search.Instead of giving q=manage* in the query, I want to do it in the schema itself so that it searches in the this fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there isn't strong requirement to use Solr analyzers, you can simply achieve above search results by using wild card '*' characters.

For eg: Suppose field name in schema is "foo" which has values "b", "ba", "bar", "bart", "bartender", & "foobar". To search all the values with "bar", you can simply query as below.

```
q=foo:(bar*)
```

Above query will return "bar", "bart" & "bartender". Hope this is what you were looking for.

**UPDATE:**

And, in case you requirement is to use Solr analyzers & filters, then **solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory** is the filter factory you should be looking for.

> This FilterFactory is very useful in matching prefix substrings (or suffix substrings if side="back") of particular terms in the index during query time. Edge n-gram analysis can be performed at either index or query time (or both), but typically it is more useful, as shown in this example, to generate the n-grams at index time with all of the n-grams indexed at the same position. At query time the query term can be matched directly without any n-gram analysis. Unlike wildcards, n-gram query terms can be used within quoted phrases.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Check field type definition for schema.xml below.

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Shishir

Comment: Hey Shishir, Ya I can do that but I dont wanna give bar* instead I wanna give just bar so that it will search by itself for the words bar,bart,bartender.

Comment: Madhur, I have updated my answer with the solr filter.

Comment: Well, in that case, could you please mark this as an answer and help others as well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to look at [stemming](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Stemming). Depending on what language you need to handle, there are different analyzers.